# Ruby - printing a "loop" to file

Tags: ruby, io

Consider the following code:

```
(1..10).each do |i| 
   thing1 = i


    aFile = File.new("input.txt", "r+")
    if aFile
        aFile.syswrite(thing1)
    else
        puts "Unable to open file!"
    end
end
```

I am trying to print every value of i (in this case 1,2,3,...,10) into the file separated by a line:

```
1
2
3
...
9
10
```

How do I do that, knowing that the following code only saves the latest output ("10").

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use File#puts

> How do I do that, knowing that the following code only saves the latest output ("10").

Don't do that. Use [File#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts) instead.

```
File.open('file', 'w') do |f|
  (1..10).each { |i| f.puts i }
end
```

### Writing an Array Instead of Looping

Note that the above can be written faster and much more compactly as:

```
File.open('file', 'w') { |f| f.puts (1..10).to_a }
```

by writing the array to the file with a single method call to #puts, rather than writing once per iteration. The results in the file remain the same, though.

Comment: you can also use `puts *(1..10)`

Comment: @GaganGami Yes, but then one needs to explain splatting a Range into an Array, which is way outside the scope of the original question or the intended answer. However, it can certainly be done, even though it saves only three characters of code at the expense of intentionality and readability. Source code should strive for clarity over cleverness. YMMV, but your splat notation has been duly noted for posterity. Thanks for the comment!